# Windows 10 will not boot with source of clone attached

Tags: windows, clone, clonezilla, gparted, uuid

I cloned a windows 10 installation from a 1T HDD to a 500G SSD using clonezilla.
Everything is fine as long as I don't attached the HDD drive that I used as the source of the clone.  Here is what I have done to the clone source so far: (all in gparted)

1. Deleted all the old partitions
2. created a new 1T partition
3. formatted it to ntfs
4. used gparted to change the uuid (gparted says something about only changing half of the uuid - i am thinking this is the source of my issue?)

What do I need to do to be able to boot with the old drive attached?  I just want to use as a mass storage device, no booting or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get this to work with one added step.  Here was the complete process if anyone else hits this:

1. **Make sure your cloned drive is working and you have a backup before you blow away the source disk then. do the following under gparted** - I had to make use of my backup, because at one point windows tried to "fix" the problem itself and just made matters worse.
2. delete all the partitions off the old drive
3. create a new partition table (I think this step is key)
4. create your new ntfs partition
5. reboot

I am not sure exactly what was going on but it seemed like even though I was booting off the new drive, when the old drive was present (even after the steps taken in the question), the boot manager somehow saw the old drive and thought windows should be on that drive (which of course it was not).  After following the 4 steps above, I was able to cleanly (and quickly) boot windows 10 and saw the old (now empty) drive ready for use.